# Having problems installing GRUB on a dual-boot RAID config

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot, grub, raid-0

I've created two RAID 0 partitions on my drives: a 500 GB and a 60 GB. I'm trying to install Ubuntu on the smaller partition (I've already put Windows 7 on the larger one), and every time I get right to the last part of installation, it says GRUB couldn't be installed.

```
"The grub package failed to install in \target\......."
```

Could anyone help me please? I'm not really a Linux expert.

Answer (score 0):

You have a proper raid adapter, no?

If you have a motherboard-raid then dmraid is what you need. I'm sure there is a guide for Ubuntu some where. Basically what you need is a kernel (and an inintrd) which supports your motherboards raid flavour. Let me have a look...

Here we are: [Ubuntu fakeraid guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto)

I think you'll be better of asking for support in the Ubuntu forums. It should not be very difficult to get this going :) gl & hf